# How to SELECT for the following in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a user system where user accounts can own subordinate accounts.

To express this relationship I have the following mysql tables:

```
TABLE ACCOUNTS
ID
name

TABLE OWNEDACCOUNTS
accountID -> ACCOUNTS(ID)
ownerID -> ACCOUNTS(ID)
```

Though it isn't obvious from these tables, this relationship can only go 2 levels deep:

Account -> Sub-Account -> Sub-Sub-Account

Currently I am able to SELECT all of the sub-accounts that belong to a top level account with the following:

```
SELECT  a.ID
FROM    accounts AS a
JOIN    ownedAccounts AS o
ON      o.accountID = a.ID
        AND o.ownerID = ?
```

However, what I'd really like is to SELECT all of the sub-accounts AND all of the sub-sub accounts that belong to a single top level account.  How do I do this?

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ...
From accounts AS a
    Join ownedAccounts AS o
        On o.accountID = a.ID
    Join accounts AS owner1
        On owner1.ID = o.ownerID
    Left Join ownedAccounts AS o2
        On o2.accountID = owner1.ID
    Left Join accounts As owner2
        On owner2.ID = o2.ownerID
Where o.ownerID = ?
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I am having trouble getting this to work.  It just returns a 0 result set.  Not sure what I may be missing...

Comment: @user1031947 - It is probably the case that not all accounts have subaccounts. I've altered the joins to left joins. I'm assuming that each account has an owner so I left the first two joins as inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

This should list every account you have, and a count of it's subs and sub-subs.  Hope that's a good starting point.

```
SELECT  a.ID, count(sub.accountID), count(subsub.accountID)
FROM    accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN    ownedAccounts AS sub ON      sub.ownerID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN    ownedAccounts AS subsub ON      subsub.ownerID = sub.accountID
```